# adding data to arrays in python with for loops from sql data return

Tags: python, sql, arrays, loops

I'm trying to add data to an array inside a loop as each row is column and row is returned.

my objective is to sort the columns into a few arrays but this does not appear to be working. i;ve been googling all afternoon about how to do this in python. W3 schools is  demonstrating something like this but it wont work, nor will their simple array examples e.g.  array[0] = "text" ,  and keeps returning errors that NameError: 'ReturnedUser_id' is not defined.

I then wish to pass these arrays out once i turn this code into a function.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(

import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
  user="xxxxxxx",
  passwd="xxxxxx",
  database="vmware"
)

print(mydb)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("select UserID, VMName, VMTemplate FROM VM WHERE CommissionStatus='commissioned';")


c = 0
for (User_id, VMName, VMTemplate) in mycursor:

    c += 1

    ReturnedUser_id[c] = User_id
    ReturnedVMName[c] = VMName
    ReturnedVMTemplate[c] = VMTemplate
```

Comment: You forgot to define ReturnedUser_id, ReturnedVMName and ReturnedVMTemplate - maybe: `ReturnedVMTemplate = []` and then use it like `ReturnedVMTemplate.append()`

Comment: Btw - I would strongly suggest tho that instead of 3 lists, you create a `class VM`, you add a `from_row()` static method to init the class from a SQL row and you store all of the data in a list of VM instances :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem with the current architecture you need to replace your logic with:

```
ReturnedUser_id = []
ReturnedVMName = [] 
ReturnedVMTemplate = []

for (User_id, VMName, VMTemplate) in mycursor:
    ReturnedUser_id.append(User_id)
    ReturnedVMName.append(VMName)
    ReturnedVMTemplate.append(VMTemplate)
```

However I would do:

```
class VM:
    def __init__(self, user_id, name, template):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.name = name
        self.template = template

    @staticmethod
    def from_row(row):
        return VM(row[0], row[1], row[2])

all_vms = []
for row in mycursor:
    all_vms.append(VM.from_row(row))
```

This allows you later to add more fiends and functionality in the VM class and instead of passing around three lists, you only pass one!

Comment: Option A might be easier to work with for the time being. Is there a way to pass all three arrays in return?

Comment: Yup, `return a, b, c` should do it. It would actually return a 3-item tuple I think